# One question about $L^1(G/K)$ and its closed subalgebra of $K$-invariant functions $L^1(G)^{\sharp}$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras, tauberian-theorems

Can someone please clarify explicitly why: "The smallest closed subspace of $L^1(G/K)$ containing $L^1(G/K)^{\sharp}$ and invariant under the (left) $G$-action, is the full space $L^1(G/K)$".

Where $G$ is a locally compact group, $L^1(G/K)$ the convolution space of all complex-valued integrable functions on $G/K$ and $L^1(G/K)^{\sharp}$  denote the closed subalgebra of $K$-invariant functions in $L^1(G/K)$, such that $K$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $G$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does $K$-invariant mean left-$K$-invariant?  If so, why is $\mathrm L^1(G)^\sharp$ even contained in $\mathrm L^1(G/K)$?  If it means right-$K$-invariant, then it seems to me that $\mathrm L^1(G)^\sharp$ *equals* $\mathrm L^1(G/K)$.  Maybe it means bi-$K$-invariant?

Comment: @ LSpice; $L^1(G/K)^{\sharp}$  denote the closed subalgebra of $K$-invariant  functions (or radial-functions) in $L^1(G/K)$, which can be identified with the subalgebra of $L^1(G)$ consisting of all $K$-bi-invariant functions on $G$

Comment: Where does this quote come from? That is, you have put the claim in quote marks: does this mean it comes from a particular paper or book?